# Does anyone know of a way to control two sets of switches at once?

Tags: switches

[image]

I would like to control the two switches in the picture at the same time.

So for example when the left switch is in position 1 the second switch is also in position 1.

Is a 2-pole rotary switch what I'm looking for?

Also sorry if the way I used the schematics for the switches doesn't make since.
Basically I want the switches to select between different resistor branches.

Comment: `yes` and `yes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a 2P4T rotary switch will work.  E-Switch and C&K are companies I have used.

The schematic does not show the resistor values.  If they are above a few K ohms, then an equivalent CMOS analog switch could work.  You still would need at least a 1P4T switch (or its elect4onic equivalent), but the switch now would handle control signals rather than the actual circuit signals.  With this, the circuit performance might improve with the wire runs to the switch being replaced by much shorter pc board traces.

What is the purpose of R7-R10?

Comment: R7-R10 aren't actually resistors they were place holders. They would actually be dc-dc converters regulating in voltage to help lower the power dissipated in the linear regulator

Comment: @drc why would you need to change the ldo reference and output voltage based on the input voltage?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a DP4T slide switch such as [this](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/C&K/SS-24E06-TG_5_(P).pdf) C&K one:

(Photo from Digikey):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The few options you have are physical switches like the rotary switches you mentioned, gang push button switches (don't have to cycle between states which may not be ideal), use switches to trigger relays, or if only for low current a bus ic or a digital solution to control some transistors or mosfets or relays.

Another physical switch could just be a basic 2p4t slider switch.